# Can we uses google analytics to analyze stats for our API?

Tags: google-analytics

I have APIs. My websites, my IOS apps, and other stuffs. We uses our own stats algorithm.

Then we think we should uses google analytics instead.

However, it's API. It's not a website. No javascript should be involved. We should contact google everything something happens. Just like in android and IOS app.

Can that be done?

Is google analytics the best way to do it?

The API uses php and asp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the best way to do it, but for GA you can use a Measurement Protocol:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/